# Unsure about the convergence radius of a series.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence

I'm trying to find all $x \in \mathbb{R}$ such that the series $ \sum_{1}^{\infty}(k-\sqrt{k^2+1})(x+2)^k$ is convergent. I used the root test but I'm a little unsure of my result. Let $a_k=(k-\sqrt{k^2+1})(x+2)^k $, then observe:
$$ C=\lim_{k \rightarrow \infty}\sup \sqrt[\leftroot{-2}\uproot{2}k]{|a_k|}=\lim_{k \rightarrow \infty}\sup \sqrt[\leftroot{-2}\uproot{2}k]{|(k-\sqrt{k^2+1})||(x+2)^k|} = \lim_{k \rightarrow \infty}\sup |x+2| \sqrt[\leftroot{-2}\uproot{2}k]{|(k-\sqrt{k^2+1})|} 
$$
$$ = |x+2|\lim_{k \rightarrow \infty}\sup \sqrt[\leftroot{-2}\uproot{2}k]{|k|\bigg|1-\sqrt{1+ \frac{1}{k^2}}\bigg|} = |x+2| \lim_{k \rightarrow \infty} \sup \sqrt[\leftroot{-2}\uproot{2}k]{|k|} \sqrt[\leftroot{-2}\uproot{2}k]{\bigg|1-\sqrt{1+ \frac{1}{k^2}} \bigg|}. 
 $$ Then I split the limits to calculate them:
$$ \lim_{k\rightarrow \infty}\sup \sqrt[\leftroot{-2}\uproot{2}]{1+ \frac{1}{k^2}}=1, \lim_{k\rightarrow \infty} \sup \sqrt[\leftroot{-2}\uproot{2}k]{|k|}=1, \lim_{k\rightarrow \infty}\sup \sqrt[\leftroot{-2}\uproot{2}]{|1-\sqrt{1}|}=0
 $$ At the end we have:
$$|x+2|(\lim_{k \rightarrow \infty}\sup1) (\lim_{k\rightarrow \infty}\sup0 )= 0.$$ Thus the series converges absolutely on $\mathbb{R}$, but I feel like I made a mistake particularly in the nested roots so I would appreciate if someone could take a second look at the algebra.

Comment: Just because $f(k)\to 0$ doesn’t mean $\sqrt[k]{f(k)}\to 0.$ Simple example: $f(k)=\frac1{2^k}.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It makes no sense to turn those roots of order $k$ into square roots, as you do after you have split those limits.

You have\begin{align}\lim_{k\to\infty}\sqrt[k]{\left|k-\sqrt{k^2+1}\right|}&=\lim_{k\to\infty}\sqrt[k]{\sqrt{k^2+1}-k}\\&=\lim_{k\to\infty}\frac1{\sqrt[k]{\sqrt{k^2+1}+k}}\\&=1,\end{align}since$$2k\leqslant\sqrt{k^2+1}+k\leqslant\sqrt{k^2+k^2}+k=(\sqrt2+1)k$$and $\lim_{k\to\infty}\sqrt[k]{\lambda k}=1$ for every $\lambda>0$. So, your series converge (absolutely) if $|x+2|<1$ and it diverges if $|x+2|>1$. If $x=-1$, it diverge (use the comparison test and the fact that the harmonic series diverges), and if $x=-3$ then it converges (by the alternate series test).